# How to use group by sqlite query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

In sqlite the group by query works...but in android the query doesn't work...how to use group by query in android.

The error says:

> Syntax error,Delete this token(Group by bname),
>   SELECT  boname,bname,SUM(amount) FROM Auction where boname ="+boatno.getText().toString() Group by bname,null)

```
protected void adddata1() {

    Database db=new Database(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("SELECT  boname,bname,SUM(amount) FROM Auction where boname ="+boatno.getText().toString() Group by bname,null);//the problem line

    cus.moveToFirst();

    int j=0,k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
    {
        if(cus.getString(0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(boatno.getText().toString()))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "entered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            bn.setText(cus.getString(1));
            Log.e("", cus.getString(1));

            amount.setText(cus.getString(2));

            Log.e("", cus.getString(2));
            adddata();
            tr1.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            adddata();
            search.setClickable(false);

            j++;
        }
        else
        {

        }

        cus.moveToNext();
    }

    if(j==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There is no data's on such Boat's",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass value in `'(single quote)` in query

```
   Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("SELECT  boname,bname,SUM(amount) FROM Auction where boname ='"+ boatno.getText().toString() +"' Group by bname",null);
```